# List variable containing string not getting rendered in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of names, which I render at two different places in a HTML at one place it works fine, the other time it disappears.

```
names= ['a','b','c','d']
```

In the HTML code I am printing

```
{{names}}
```

this gives me the correct results. When I use the same string in a javascript it stops working but if I replace the variable by

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

then it works fine.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing some larger chunks of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean 'in a javascript'? Is that in a template being rendered by Django, and if not how are you expecting it to be evaluated?

Comment: document.getElementById('leaderboard_swf').callSWF('asMethod',{{final_score_list}},{{final_level}},{{final_challengeswon}},{{final_bronze}},{{final_silver}},{{final_gold}},{{names}});

If I do not put the line names in the end it works. Otherwise it does not. But if I replace {{names}} by its value it works.

Comment: That did not answer the question even slightly. Where is this code? What sort of file? How is it being rendered?

Comment: The javascript code is in an HTML. The python code is rendered in a django template. 

I tried rendering a string into javascscript. Having the same problem, the string gets rendered in the HTML not the javascript

Comment: You are not being clear. Is the javascript in a Django template or not?